# Sed three pattern search

Tags: unix, sed

Say I have a file as below. I want to  do a three pattern search fetching all between [ and ] and  which  is having my search string(111) inside:

```
Msg: [
blah abc blah
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah blah..
blah efg blah blah
blah blah..
]
Msg: [
111
]
Msg: [
222
]
```

I see just below printed:

```
Msg: [
222
]
```

I tried `pcregrep -M  'Msg:.*(\n|.)*]'`  but cant  figure out how to  get the  wanted pattern alone. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed version

```
sed '#n
 /Msg: \[/,/]/ {
    H
    /Msg: \[/ x
    /]/ {
       x
# next search pattern is your string
       s/111/&/p
       }
    }' YourFile
```

posix version so `--posix` on GNU sed

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this way

```
sed  -n '/Msg: \[/N;/\n111/N;/\n\]/p' File_Name
```

**Explanation :**

```
/Msg: \[/N -- If the "Msg : [" the pattern is found get the another line and append to the pattern space  .    
/\n111/N   -- Then the new appended line is "111" again get the another line and append to the pattern space .
/\n\]/p    --The last line is "]" the print the pattern space and get your expect result.
```

**Output :**

```
Msg: [
111
]
```

Or you need that exact pattern  use this way

```
sed  -rn '/Msg: \[/N;/\n111/N;/\n\]/s/^.*\n(.*)\n.*$/\1/p' File_Name
```

**Output :**

```
111
```

Comment: Sorry . but this is not working if i have say Msg: [
222
111
]
my search string may not be the only string inside  the  block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use `gnu awk` (Gnu to multiple characters in `RS`)

```
awk -v RS='Msg: \\[' '/111/ {print RS $0}' file
Msg: \[
111
]
```

This tell `awk` to split the post by `Msg: [`, then its just the pick the pattern and add the RS.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number `111` only,

```
$ pcregrep -M -o '\]\nMsg:\s*\[\n\K[^\]\[]*(?=\n\]\nMsg:)' file
111
```

To get the whole block,

```
$ pcregrep -M -o '\]\n\KMsg:\s*\[\n[^\]\[]*\](?=\nMsg:)' file
Msg: [
111
]
```